# I can't edit User_Setup/GitHub in VS Code

Tags: header, shared-libraries

I am trying to edit User_Setup_Select.h files to comment and uncomment but I can't change the code. I can change the **same** file in Sublime Text but VS Code won't allow me to either directly or in Platform IO.

I can't edit the code